# Vue.js - print only value instead of JSON key-value notation?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

The relevant markup looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="object in tableData">
      <td v-for="field in object">{{field}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The data basically looks like this:

```
{
    Internal_key: "TESTKEY_1",
    extensiontable_itc: {
        description_itc: "EXTENSION_ITC_1"    ​
    },
    extensiontable_sysops: {
        description_sysops: "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_1"
    }    
}
```

​​​This type of object resides within an array. There might be any number of these objects inside this array.

Currently, this setup creates this output inside myList.vue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVd9Z.jpg

Now, I only want the values to show up, not this key-value JSON notation ^^ how can I do that?

Comment: You must use `{{field.description_itc}}` if  you want display value of `description_itc` field

Comment: You're iterating through an object that might have an nested object set as property value. In your scenario the nested object contains a single key/value-pair. Is this always the case? What should happen if the nested object contains 0 or more than 1 properties? For example `extensiontable_itc` is set to `{a: "some value", b: "another value"}`

Comment: @3limin4t0r this is not necessarily always the case. These nested objects can contain any number of properties/key-value pairs. Your example assumes this correctly.

Comment: Did you already think about how you want to display all those values in a single `<td>` element? You currently have three columns, corresponding to `"Internal_key"`, `"extensiontable_itc"` and `"extensiontable_sysops"`. Meaning that the `"extensiontable_itc"` field should hold all values of the nested object. Is this the intention? Or is the intention to create separate columns for each property in a nested object?

Comment: @3limin4t0r the intention is to create separate columns for each property in a nested object, yes! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have some fields which are objects and some which are not, you need to test that.  Here's one way to do it:

```
<tr v-for="object in data">
  <td v-for="field in object">
    <template v-if="typeof field === 'object'">
      <div v-for="item in field">
        {{ item }}
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      {{ field }}
    </template>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/03eh18zy/)

Comment: Your approach works like a charm!!!!
However, about {{ Object.values(field)[0] }}.
This only is helpful if the object contains exactly one property. However, the object may contain any number of properties (except 0...or less of course :D). 
How can I do that? ;)

Comment: Ok.  There was no mention of that or example in the code or screenshot (each object has only 1 property).  I edited the answer to list any amount of properties underneath each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can get value and name(Key) from the object and use it something like;

```
 < td v-for="(value, name) in object">
     {{ value }}
 </td >
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the behavior hasnt changed so far, but still thanks for this great insight into vue and its v-for! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. However it might be more efficient to just map the data before putting it into the template.

```html
<template v-for="field in object">
    <td v-if="null !== field && typeof(field) === 'object'">
        <span v-for="thingy in field">{{ thingy }}</span>
    </td>
    <td v-else>{{ field }}</td>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me what "mapping" the data means here? Or point me somewhere where it is explained?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that fits my needs, here is the markup which processes the datastructure shown in OP accordingly and dynamically generates the desired list:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uevzR.jpg

```
<template v-for="element in tableData">
  <tr>
      <template v-for="field in element">

        <template v-if="typeof field==='object'">
          <td v-for="nestedObjectValue in field">
            {{nestedObjectValue}}
          </td>
        </template>

        <template v-else>
          <td>
            {{field}}
          </td>
        </template>

      </template>
      <td><button v-on:click="changeRecord">Aendern</button></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```